# how to display difference between user last login time and current time in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I trying to display difference between user last login time to current time in index page.

This is my controller......

```
<?php

class front_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->check_login();
    }

    public function check_login() {
        if ($this->session->userdata('id') == "") {
            redirect(base_url());
        }
    }

}
?>
```

This is my model......

```
<?php
public function login() {
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $result = $this->db->get('auth_user');
    if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
        $result = $result->row();
        $data = array(
            'id' => $result->id,
            'username' => $result->username,
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        $this->db->where('id', $result->id);
        $this->db->update('auth_user', array('last_login' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

And this is my index file.....

```
<div id="user_info" style="padding: 15px 20px 0px 20px;">
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#clock").clock();
        });
    </script>
    <p>
    <div id="clock" style="letter-spacing: 2px;"></div>
    Welcome, <strong><?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?></strong> Last Login: 2 minutes<br/>
    <a href="logout"><b>Logout</b></a>
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store login `last_login` time in session for using in view

```
public function login(){
$this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
$this->db->where('password',md5($this->input->post('password')));
$result = $this->db->get('auth_user');
if($result->num_rows() > 0){
    $result = $result->row();
    $data = array(
        'id'        => $result->id,
        'username'  => $result->username,
        'last_login'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    $this->db->where('id',$result->id);
    $this->db->update('auth_user', array('last_login'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}
```

In view file you can use `timespan` function of date helper for calculating the time.

```
<?php
   $this->load->helper('date'); 
 ?>
 <div id="user_info" style="padding: 15px 20px 0px 20px;">
 <script>
 $(function(){$("#clock").clock();});
 </script>
 <p>
 <div id="clock" style="letter-spacing: 2px;"></div>
 Welcome, <strong>
 <?php echo $this->session->userdata('username');?>  </strong>
 Last Login: 
<?php
 echo timespan(strtotime($this>session>userdata('last_login')),strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),4) 
?><br/>
  <a href="logout"><b>Logout</b></a>
                </p>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

store the last login time in session when do login (before updating login time). then use that session to display last login time
Model :

```
public function login(){
    $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password',md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $result = $this->db->get('auth_user');
    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
        $result = $result->row();
        $data = array(
            'id'        => $result->id,
            'username'  => $result->username,
            'last_login'=> $result->last_login, // store in session
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        $this->db->where('id',$result->id);
        $this->db->update('auth_user', array('last_login'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

In index(view) file :

```
<div id="user_info" style="padding: 15px 20px 0px 20px;">
                    <script>
                        $(function(){$("#clock").clock();});
                    </script>
                    <p>
                        <div id="clock" style="letter-spacing: 2px;"></div>
                        Welcome, <strong><?php echo $this->session->userdata('username');?></strong> Last Login: <?php echo $this->session->userdata('last_login');?<br/>
                        <a href="logout"><b>Logout</b></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
```